# YouTube automatically resizing

Tags: youtube

If a YouTube video is embed in a web page is there a way to have a small size (example 200 x 150) then have it re-size larger (example 400 x 300) when it is played.  An example would be when a video is received in Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding a click event to the  tag that will then resize the  element to a larger size, but I'm guessing that the flash video player will hijack the click event and not bubble it up to the DOM.

Otherwise, you can have a poster image placeholder, and when that is clicked, you replace the image with the actual video player at whatever size you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to let javascript listen to the player's onStateChange event, when state changes to "1" (playing), you change the width and height to the new size. Maybe something like this could work:

```
var player = document.getElementById("youtube-player");

function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
  if (evt.data == "1") {
    player.style.width = "400px";
    player.style.height = "300px";
  }
}

player.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
```

You can play around with the javascript api here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo And here is the reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events This assumes it's an embed on your on web page, I don't really get what you mean with "... video is recieved in Gmail".